# How to customize the body tag for TAL in plone main_template equivalent to "ondragstart="false"?

Tags: python, plone, template-tal, zpt, template-metal

I wish to customize the main_template of plone 4.1 to prevent mouse selection and drag. Don't know where exactly and how to do it in the body tag. Also need a simple and quick reference for learning TAL, TALES, METAL. Something for beginners. Please guide. I wish to prevent copy/paste form the browser. I have  customized it for the file preview but unable to do the same for the main_template.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to customize the body tag is to install [plone.app.theming](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming). It is easier to understand, can be done through the web and is more likely to remain compatible through upgrades. It is compatible with Plone 4.1 and included in 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a simple `ondragstart="false"` attribute, you don't need any knowledge of TAL, TALES or METAL.

TAL is a XML-aware templating language, it uses namespaces and XML attributes to 'blend in' into the template structure. As such, you can add extra attributes to tags outside of the TAL-specific attributes.

Simply customize the `main_template` file and add the attribute to the body tag:

```xml
<body ondragstart="false" class="" tal:attributes="..." />
```

If you still want to read up on TAL, TALES and METAL, you can read the Zope 2 book, [chapter 10: Using Zope Page Templates](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/ZPT.html), [chapter 13: Advanced Page Templates](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AdvZPT.html) and [appendix C: Zope Page Templates Reference](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html).

Comment: Thank you but I dont seem to understand where exactly to add this in the body on main template along with other tags given by default which is also required:   <body tal:define="isRTL portal_state/is_rtl;
sl python:plone_view.have_portlets('plone.leftcolumn', view);
sr python:plone_view.have_portlets('plone.rightcolumn', view);
body_class python:plone_view.bodyClass(template, view);"
tal:attributes="class body_class;
dir python: isRTL and 'rtl' or 'ltr'">    ... If i add it immediately after <body ondrag... , it compiles but reduces the window size of the submenu in Plone

Comment: if it compiles and you didn't remove any of the `tal:` attributes, then you have a CSS problem, not a TAL problem. Check your output on-screen with and without the extra attribute and check that everything else is behaving as expected.

Comment: The moment I save the default code(main_template) to customize and refresh the browser the window size if the submenu is reduced without any changes in the code